# Problems with encoding while invoking swi-prolog from PHP

Tags: php, encoding, swi-prolog

I'm invoking SWI-prolog from PHP, sending a question and getting result. I'm using **exec()** function for that:

```
$goal = "all_facts('S').";
$cmd = "/software/swipl/bin/swipl -f Domain.pl -g " . $goal . " -t halt";
```

The predicate **all_facts()** returns facts about counties, in this example - square.

There are a lot of facts about countries in Russian in the prolog file as it needed for my site.
SWI-prolog returns an answer with Russian symbols and every thing is OK.

The problem rises when I'm trying to use Russian symbols in request, for example:

```
 $goal = "all_facts('Столица').";
```

Then I'm running this request exactly in SWI-prolog, I get the correct answer. But then I'm asking it from PHP, I don't get the answer at all.

So, I guess, bugs appear while sending request and SWI-prolog gets distorted question, so it can't find an answer.

I've already changed encoding of SWI-Prolog (using environment variable LANG), encoding of page, tried to change encoding of PHP exec (not sure, if it worked).
Maybe, I really need to change PHP exec encoding, but I am  doing it wrong.

How can I do it?

Just in case, part of the prolog file:

```
facts('Австралия','S', 7686850).
facts('Австрия', 'S', 83871).
facts('Азербайджан','S', 86600).
facts('Австралия','Столица', 'Канберра').
facts('Австрия', 'Столица', 'Вена').
facts('Азербайджан','Столица', 'Баку').
all_facts(C):- findall(X:Y, facts(X,C,Y), All), write(All).
```

PHP code:

```php
<?
    $goal = "all_facts('Столица').";
    $cmd = "/software/swipl/bin/swipl -f Domain.pl -g ".$goal." -t halt";

    if (exec($cmd)) {
        $output = exec($cmd);
    }
    else {
        echo "Error!";
    }

    $output = str_replace(array("[","]"), "", $output);
    $facts = explode(",", $output);
    $length = count($facts);
    echo "<ul>";
    for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
        $all_facts[$i]= explode(":", $facts[$i]);
        echo "<li>", $all_facts[$i][0], " - ", $all_facts[$i][1], "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Comment: How are you capturing the output of the `all_facts/1` call?

Comment: I've added php listing above.

Comment: Not familiar with PHP but your code seems fine. Did you experimented with facts contain only ASCII characters? So that you can confirm that's an encoding issue?

Comment: Yes. When I've tested code with ASCII characters everything works fine. It works even when I recive russian characters from prolog. But it doesn't send them correctly.

Comment: I can only assume that you also checked the encoding the source file holding the PHP code and ensured that's the same used through your workflow?

Comment: Maybe you can modify the `all_facts/1` to call `current_prolog_flag(encoding, Encoding)` and write out the `Encoding` value before the `findall/3` to check that the encoding is UTF-8 as you expect.

Comment: I've modified `all_facts/1` as you advised. Now it shows that encoding is "text" in both cases: when I send request with only english characters and with russian characters too. As I understood from this: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=widechars - 'text' means in my context - utf8. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion on the comments, I suggest you add at the **first line** of the `Domain.pl` file the following directive:

```
:- encoding(utf8).
```

and ensure that the text editor used to edit the file saves it as a UTF-8 file. Your modified version of the `all_facts/1` predicate should now write `utf8`.